# Is the regular conditional probability of $\mathbb P$ dominated by $\mathbb P$ almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, absolute-continuity

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, let $\mathcal G$ be a $\sigma$-subfield, and let $\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}$ be a regular conditional probability for $\mathbb P$ given $\mathcal G$. That is, for all $x \in X$, $\mathbb P_x^{\mathcal E}$ is a probability measure, $x \mapsto \mathbb P_x(A)$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable for all $A \in \mathcal X$, and
$$\mathbb P(A \cap G) = \int_G \mathbb P^{\mathcal G}_x(A)\mathbb P(dx)$$
holds for all $A \in \mathcal X$ and $G \in \mathcal G$.

> Is it true that $P_x^{\mathcal G} \ll \mathbb P$ for almost every $x$?

I can confirm that this is true if $\mathcal X$ is separable, but I'm not sure it holds in general.

Comment: My guess is that this is false without separability of the sigma field.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was starting to think that too. For instance, separability is needed to ensure that the regular conditional probabilities are almost surely unique, so maybe we can get a counterexample when a.s. uniqueness fails.

Comment: i don't know if this helps, but I was trying to disprove the absolute continuity of a joint probability measure $p_{X,Y}$ with respect to the product of its marginals $p_X\times p_Y$ and in the end it was enough to consider $X\sim\mathcal U([0,1])$, $Y=X$ and the set $A=\{(x,x):x\in[0,1]\}$, then $p_{X,Y}(A)=1$ and $p_X\times p_Y(A)=0$. I feel like this could be adapted for your counter example since your conditional probability measure is just a Rado-Nykodym derivative of a joint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=[0,1]^2$, $\mathcal X$ is its Borel algebra and $\mathcal G=\{[0,1]\times B : [0,1]\times B \in \mathcal X\}$. If $\mathbb P(A) = \lambda(\{a:(a,a)\in A\})$ for any $A\in \mathcal X$ (with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$) then for $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ we have $\mathbb P_{(x,y)}^{\mathcal G}(A)=1_{A}\{(y,y)\}$ and $\mathbb P(\{(0,0)\})=0\neq 1=\mathbb P_{(0,0)}^{\mathcal G}(\{(0,0)\})$.

Comment: Thanks, but there are some things I don't understand here. First, not every member of $\mathcal X$ is of the form $A \times B$ (where I assume you take $A$ and $B$ to be Borel subsets of $[0,1]$). Second, I don't get $\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}_x(A \times B) = 1_{A \cap B}(x)$. $\mathbb P^{\mathcal G}$ is a function on $X$, so $x$ must be in $[0,1]^2$, but then $1_{A \cap B}(x)$ does not seem well-formed.

Comment: I tried too fix it but I'm not convinced. I think the idea may be good but I made stupid mistakes.